# How to find the type of a list using Novacode DocX?

Tags: novacode-docx

I'm parsing a .docx document using Novacode DocX, and so far I can detect if a paragraph is part of a list with `Paragraph.IsListItem`. However, I want to distinguish between lists numbered with Arabic numbers (1. 2. 3.), Roman numbers (I. II. III.) or letters (a. b. c.).

I can't find any property in `Paragraph` that gives me this information. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: What have you dried so far? Where did you look? Do you have a link to the official documentation?